# Show that $f$ is constant using Maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, limsup-and-liminf, analytic-functions, maximum-principle

Let $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ and $ \bar{D}=\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$. Suppose that $f : \bar{D} \setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function that satisfies:

(i) $f$ is analytic in $D \setminus \{0\}$;

(ii) $\limsup_{z \to 0}|f(z)|< \infty$;

(iii) $f(z)$ is equal to a finite constant on the unit circle $|z|=1$.

Prove that $ f$ is a constant function.

The first thing coming into my mind that I may use the Maximum Modulus Principle for this problem. On $|z|=1$, $f$ is bounded, I want to prove that $f$ has a maximum on $D  $, but I can't see how to use the assumption (ii). Does it mean that

$$\forall \delta>0, \sup|f(z)|_{|z|\leq \delta} < \infty ?$$

Do I have to prove that $f$ is continuous at $z=0$?

Could you please help me with this problem? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: (ii) means that $f$ is bounded near $0$. Since it is analytic on $D \setminus \{0\}$, (ii) implies that $f$ extend to an analytic function on the whole $D$

Comment: Then you can use the Maximum modulus principal on each $\{ z \, : \, |z| < r \}$ for every $0<r<1$ and see what happens when $r$ tends to $1$ using (iii)

Comment: @AlexL Thank you for your help. Do you mean if $f$ is constant on each $\{z: |z|<r\}$ for every $0<r<1$, then taking $r \to 1$, since $f$ is continuous and $f=c$ on $|z|=1$, this means that $f=c$ throughout $\bar{D}$?

Comment: $f$ is a priori not constant on each $\{ z \; : \; |z|<r \}$, But it hits its maximum M_r and minimum m_r on $\{ z \; : \; |z|=r \}$. $M_r$ must be non decreasing as $r \to 1$ and $m_r$ is non increasing as $r \to 1$. Then use (iii) and the continuity of $f$ on $\bar{D}$ to see that $|c| \leqslant m_r \leqslant M_r \leqslant |c|$ ($c$ is the value of $f$ on $\{ |z|=1\}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to solve this problem based on your advice, please let me know if my solution is correct.

We have $ \limsup_{z \to 0}|f(z)| < \infty$, so there exists a neighborhood of $0$ on which $f$ is bounded. Since $ f$ is analytic in $D \setminus \{0\}$, by Riemann's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity), we get $f $ is analytically extendable over $0$, then $f$ is also continuously extendable over $0$.

Put $f(z) =c$ on $|z|=1$, $c$ is a constant. Consider the function $g(z) = f(z)-c$, then $g(z)=0$ on $|z|=1$.

Since $f$ is continuous and analytic in $\bar{D}$, $g$ is continuous and analytic in $\bar{D}$ as well,  by Maximum Modulus Principle, $g(z)=0$ in $\bar{D}$.

Thus, $f$ is a constant in $\bar{D}$.

Answer (score 1):

ii) says that $f$ is bounded near $0$ and this implies that $f$ has  removable singularity at $0$. So we can treat $f$ as  a holomorphic function on $D$ by assigning a suitable value at $0$. See Riemann 's theorem in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity

Let $f=c$ on $|z|=1$. By considering $f-c$ instead of $f$ we may suppose $f=0$ on the boundary. Now MMP implies that $f=0$ in $D$.

Comment: Could you please help me check my answer above? Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you think about my solution in the Answer Part below? I applied Riemann's Theorem and then Max.Mod.Principle. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @anna The part where you wrote ??? is not clear. I think MMP applied dierectly to $f$ does  not yield the proof. You have to apply it to $f-c$.

Comment: My bad, I mean that is a contradiction with (*)

Comment: @anna Sorry, I don't see any contradiction there.

Comment: May I ask why I could not apply MMP directly for $f$? since in MMP, I see that it is only a constant in general?

Comment: @anna You can apply MMP but it yields nothing.

Comment: I made a change, could you please give me some feedback on my solution? Thank you so much

Comment: @anna Yes, now it is correct.

Comment: @Kama Murthy Thank you very much for helping me a lot.